# Using sed to replace only the first two regex catches with different strings

Tags: sed, regular-expression

So I'm trying to change two instances of a regex pattern to two different strings with sed like:

```
sed -E "s/\\t([A-Za-z]|[-])+$/\\t`get_addr.py -1`/" /path/to/file.ext
sed -E "s/\\t([A-Za-z]|[-])+$/\\t`get_addr.py -2`/" /path/to/file.ext
```

I've tried a lot of things, and done a solid amount of manpage scouring, but I just can't quite figure out how make it happen.

Is there a way I can tell sed to replace each match with a different string with something like

```
sed -E "s/\\t([A-Za-z]|[-])+$/[1st replacement],[2nd replacement]/" /path/to/file.ext
```

and/or is there a way I can specify in the regex that I'm looking for the nth match, so that I can just call sed twice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At least in GNU sed, I think you can do something like

```
sed -e '0,/pattern/ s//replacement1/' -e '0,/pattern/ s//replacement2/' file
```

e.g. given a file

```
abc
def
abc
ghi
abc
jkl
```

then

```
$ sed -e '0,/abc/ s//XYZ/' -e '0,/abc/ s//UVW/' file
XYZ
def
UVW
ghi
abc
jkl
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you! Totally got it to work. In my case I had to change the 0 in the second script to 2, like `$ sed -e '0,/abc/ s//XYZ/' -e '2,/abc/ s//UVW/' file` Not exactly sure why that is though, when I changed the 0 in the second script to 1, it overwrote both of the target texts with the second substitution, but when I changed it to 2, it worked as stated above.

Comment: Hmm... in that case it's probably not working the way I thought - use with care. I'm sure one of the gurus will be along give a better solution soon.